# Packer, Dockramp vs Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, packer

Can someone please explain the advantages/disadvantages using the following when building container images, rather than using the dockerfile.

1. Packer - tool for creating machine and container images for multiple platforms from a single source configuration
2. Dockramp -  A Client-driven Docker Container Image Builder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Packer is a tool that initially was created to create AWS AMIs or base VM images in AWS. It has been extended to be used with containers, a lot of different Virtualization software such as [VMware](https://www.vmware.com), [KVM/QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/KVM), and other cloud/IaaS providers like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/). It was developed by [Hashicorp](https://hashicorp.com/) but it's open source.
2. [Dockramp](https://github.com/jlhawn/dockramp) is an alternative to using `docker build` it uses the same
   `Dockerfile` that `docker build` would use but with some additional
   enhancements. For example, it can use accept
   [heredocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) in the `RUN`
   command for multiple line bash commands.

Docker/LXC is fairly fast but the main advantage of building images (and this applies to Virtualization images too) is that you can have a fully installed application or application stack from the get-go.  This tends to work better in autoscaling environments because it takes less time for your application to start servicing traffic either in a container or VM.

When you are creating your docker image all the time with your Dockerfile it needs to run a series of steps before becoming 'ready', hence it might take longer to start servicing traffic.

Hope it helps.